# How to call through a member function pointer?

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I'm trying to do some testing with member function pointer. What is wrong with this code? The `bigCat.*pcat();` statement doesn't compile.

```
class cat {
public:
   void walk() {
      printf("cat is walking \n");
   }
};

int main(){
   cat bigCat;
   void (cat::*pcat)();
   pcat = &cat::walk;
   bigCat.*pcat();
}
```

Answer (score 139, accepted):

More parentheses are required:

```
(bigCat.*pcat)();
^            ^
```

The function call (`()`) has higher precedence than the pointer-to-member binding operator (`.*`).  The unary operators have higher precedence than the binary operators.

Comment: @AdrianCornish:  Nope, but `pcat` does not name a member, it names the pointer-to-member declared as a local variable in `main`.

Comment: I guess it is a little like a virtual function call - Is there a good use case/problem this is good for - struggling to think how to use this for good code

Comment: @AdrianCornish: I have never actually used this feature, nor have I seen it used in code written by others. Surely it has been used by someone... but the use cases are few and far between.

Comment: @EdS. My thoughts exactly - just because you does not mean it is a good idea ;-) never seen this in 22 years of c++ but probably a lot I have not seen too

Comment: @AdrianCornish:  It's a rarely used feature.  I used it a lot in generic code, for example, I had a set of `for_each`-like algorithms that took a sequence of pointers and called a member function on each of the pointed-to objects.  It saved me from having to use ugly function binder incantations.  That was before lambda expressions made that a lot easier... if I were to rewrite all of that code, I'd probably use lambdas for most of the uses.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Would you mind emailing me a contrived example - I think I get what  you are saying but have doubts. Hopefully you can see my email from my profile. Or stick it in a pastebin

Comment: @AdrianCornish Here's a recent (last month) use case from my experience, I set up a traits class that gives me a member function pointer to the simple primary key accessor in each ORM object for which the trait is specialized. I see member function pointers around now and again, they don't appear unusual to me (although mem_fn, bind, and friends are replacing them)

Comment: @AdrianCornish:  I'll try to come up with one.  I no longer have access to the code base in which I made extensive use of this feature, but I'm sure I can come up with something.  :-)

Comment: @JamesMcNellis Appreciated if you could - always good to learn new techniques.

Comment: @Adrian Cornish: I can think of one really good use case for this code.  If you want to simulate something like a C# Delegate in C++, you can create a templated function object which takes a context (this pointer) and a member function that can be called later.  By providing a series of templated call operators, you wrap a member function in a custom delegate for a wide variety of member function signatures.  I've done this and it can be quite useful.

Comment: I find myself using it when refactoring and I see the same logic before and after a member-function call repeated again and again. That can get refactored into a function that takes a member function pointer to call so the before and after logic can be written only once.

Answer (score 19):

Today, the canonical way is using the [std::invoke](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) function template, especially in generic code. Please note, that the member function pointer comes first:

```
import <functional>;

std::invoke(pcat, bigCat);
```

What you get: Unified calling syntax for virtually anything, that is invocable.

Overhead: none.

Comment: Caveat: requires C++17 (increasingly less of a problem of course)