# Declare and use a pointer to member function in another class

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have this error, when I try to use a pointer to member function to a different class.

```
Error : sources/common/OurMenu.cpp: 
  In member function ‘void OurMenu::menuNavigation()’: sources/common/OurMenu.cpp:336:36: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in 
  ‘((OurMenu*)this)->OurMenu::_buttons.std::vector::at >(((std::vector::size_type)((OurMenu*)this)->OurMenu::_actualLine))->Button::doIt (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* ((OurMenu*)this)->OurMenu::_buttons.std::vector::at >(((std::vector::size_type)((OurMenu*)this)->OurMenu::_actualLine))->Button::doIt) (...)’
     _buttons.at(_actualLine)->doIt();
```

That's my code:

**OurMenu.hh**

```
class                           OurMenu
{
 private:
  GraphicLib                    *_window;
  OurGame                       *_game;
  gdl::Geometry                 _background;
  std::vector<gdl::Texture*>    _textures;
  std::vector<Button*>          _buttons;
  int                           _actualLine;
  int                           _time;

public:
  [...]
  void                          menuNavigation();
  void                          gameSetting();
};
```

**Button.hh**

```
class                   Button
{
 private:
  Bloc                  *_select;
  Bloc                  *_notSelect;

 public:
  Button(const float &x, const float &y, gdl::Geometry *back,
     gdl::Texture *tx, gdl::Texture *txS, glm::vec3 const &scale, void (OurMenu::*ptr)());
  ~Button();

  void                  (OurMenu::*doIt)();
  void                  isSelect();
  void                  isDeselect();
  Bloc                  *getSelect() const;
  Bloc                  *getNotSelect() const;
};
```

Button Declaration

```
 Button  *solo = new Button(2, 7, &_background, _textures.at(1), _textures.at(7), 
                           glm::vec3(0.0025, 0.0022, 0), &OurMenu::gameSetting);
```

Function call

```
solo->doIt();
```

**Button.cpp**

```
Button::Button(const float &x, const float &y, gdl::Geometry *back, 
              gdl::Texture *tx, gdl::Texture *txS, glm::vec3 const &scale, void (OurMenu::*ptr)())
{
  _select = new Bloc(0, 0, back, txS);
  _select->rotate(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0), 180);
  _select->setScale(scale);
  _select->setX(x);
  _select->setY(y);
  _select->setZ(1);

  _notSelect = new Bloc(0, 0, back, tx);
  _notSelect->rotate(glm::vec3(1, 1, 0), 180);
  _notSelect->setScale(scale);
  _notSelect->setX(x);
  _notSelect->setY(y);
  _notSelect->setZ(-1);
  doIt = ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it looks like you are trying

```
(solo->doIt)(); // need the parentheses here
```

where `solo` is of type `Button*`, however `doIt` is a pointer to member function of type`void (OurMenu::*)()`. It won't work, as the pointer to member function must be invoked on an instance of the same type, in your case `OurMenu`. If `solo` is cast-able to `OurMenu` (which is probably not), you can do

```
(static_cast<OurMenu*>(solo)->doIt)();
```

Otherwise you should either change your design. It looks like you want to invoke a menu function from your `Button` instance. If this is so, you need to create an instance of the `OurMenu` in your `Button`, and invoke the pointer on that instance, something like

```
OurMenu menu; // this is created somewhere in Button
(menu.*doIt)();
```

Comment: I want to use the doIt function in the Button class but doIt point on a OurMenu function member

Comment: You won't be able to do this, unless you can cast a `Button*` to `OurMenu*`. Pointer to member functions cannot be invoked on different object types.

Comment: sources/common/OurMenu.cpp:336:51: error: invalid static_cast from type ‘Button*’ to type ‘OurMenu*’
     static_cast<OurMenu*>(_buttons.at(_actualLine))->doIt();

I have this error when i try your tips

Comment: @MaximeLimone yes that's expected, since the types are not related. Think more about your design, why does the pointer to member function has to be of type `void(OurMenu::*)()` but you then invoke it on a `Button` instance? If you know you'll be invoke it on `Button` instances only, change the type of the pointer to member function to `void(Button::*)()`. Otherwise `Button*` itself should be related to `OurMenu*`, so you can cast `Button*` to `OurMenu*` safely; in other words should be derived from, which again doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: I have a button class when i select a button i want launch the doIt function and in my OurMenu class i have a Button vector and i have too the doIt function like gameSetting for display a new menu

Comment: What you need is to create an instance of `OurMenu`, and invoke the `doIt()` on that instance, like `OurMenu menu; (menu.*doIt)();`. I've slightly updated the edit, see if it helps. What you need to understand is that pointer to member functions can only be invoked on instances of the class they are related to.

Comment: Ok so i try that :
    `(this.*_buttons.at(_actualLine))->doIt();`
because i call the do it function in a OurMenu Function member
(sorry i didn't give information) _buttons.at(_actualLine) is a Button*

Comment: @MaximeLimone as long as what appears before `->doIt)()` is of type `OurMenu*`, it will work. Don't forget the extra set of parentheses, as mentioned in the first line of my answer, and also asked about [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12189057/3093378).

Comment: `(this.*_buttons.at(_actualLine))->doIt();`, _buttons.at(_actualLine)) this is a Button* and `this` is a OurMenu instance

Comment: @MaximeLimone As I said, if the type is ok, it should work. Just use that extra set of parentheses `( (this.*_buttons.at(_actualLine))->doIt) ();`

Comment: Ok thanks and now i have this error sources/common/OurMenu.cpp: In member function ‘void OurMenu::menuNavigation()’:
sources/common/OurMenu.cpp:336:36: error: ‘((OurMenu*)this)->OurMenu::_buttons.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::at<Button*, std::allocator<Button*> >(((std::vector<Button*>::size_type)((OurMenu*)this)->OurMenu::_actualLine))’ cannot be used as a member pointer, since it is of type ‘Button*’
     ((this.*_buttons.at(_actualLine))->doIt)();

Comment: @MaximeLimone As I told you, the compiler is just saying that the type of `(this.*_buttons.at(_actualLine))` **is not** `OurMenu*`. There is nothing you can do here, you **must** invoke the pointer to member function on a `OurMenu` instance. I cannot help you more than that, just try to understand how pointer to member functions work.

Comment: Ok Thank you so much, sorry for my english i'm french ;)

Comment: @MaximeLimone No problem, hope the answer helped a bit.