# list/vector of class methods in a class variable

Tags: c++, class, vector, function-pointers, class-method

I need to maintain a list of methods that will be executed in different orders for testing. We are moving away from C to C++ to use google framework. Is it possible to maintain a list of functions pointers to some of the class methods to be used for execution inside the class, so that they can be used after instantiation ? please refer http://cpp.sh/265y

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef void (*funcType)();

class Sample {
    public:
    vector<funcType> func_list;

    Sample();

    void formList();
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();    
};

void Sample::formList() {
    func_list.push_back(&method1);
    func_list.push_back(&method2);
    func_list.push_back(&method3);
}

void Sample::method1 () {
    cout << "method1" << endl;
}

void Sample::method2 () {
    cout << "method2" << endl;
}

void Sample::method3 () {
    cout << "method3" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Sample sample; //* = new Sample();
    sample.formList();
    vector<funcType>::iterator it;
    for (it = sample.func_list.begin(); it != sample.func_list.end(); ++it) {
         ((*it));
    }

}
```

Answer: http://cpp.sh/8rr2

Comment: Worth your time to read: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members . Lots of hints and good advice in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the dreaded pointer-to-member-function syntax:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b634f043e2fb324)</kbd>**

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Sample;

typedef void (Sample::*funcType)();

class Sample {
  public:
    vector<funcType> func_list;

    Sample(){}

    void formList();
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();
};

void Sample::formList() {
    func_list.push_back(&Sample::method1);
    func_list.push_back(&Sample::method2);
    func_list.push_back(&Sample::method3);
}

void Sample::method1() { cout << "method1" << endl; }

void Sample::method2() { cout << "method2" << endl; }

void Sample::method3() { cout << "method3" << endl; }

int main() {
    Sample sample; //* = new Sample();
    sample.formList();
    vector<funcType>::iterator it;
    for (it = sample.func_list.begin(); it != sample.func_list.end(); ++it) {
        (sample.*(*it))(); // HORRIFIC, INNIT? SEE BELOW FOR BETTER
    }
}
```

### MUCH BETTER:

However, you could be much more versatile using C++11/TR1 `std::function<>` or `boost::function<>`:

```
typedef function<void(Sample*)> funcType;

// ...
func_list.push_back(mem_fn(&Sample::method1));
func_list.push_back(mem_fn(&Sample::method2));
func_list.push_back(mem_fn(&Sample::method3));
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/accd8eacc7b2f214)</kbd>** too

```
for (it = sample.func_list.begin(); it != sample.func_list.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)(&sample); // much better
}
```

> The added versatility is mainly in that you can cater for different signatures: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36317dfefd46de7f)</kbd>**
>
> ```
> class Sample {
>   public:
>     vector<funcType> func_list;
>
>     Sample(){}
>
>     void formList();
>     void method1(int);
>     void method2(std::string);
>     void method3(double, double, double);
> };
>
> void Sample::formList() {
>     using std::placeholders::_1;
>     func_list.push_back(bind(&Sample::method1, _1, 42));
>     func_list.push_back(bind(&Sample::method2, _1, "Hello world"));
>     func_list.push_back(bind(&Sample::method3, _1, 1, 2, 3));
> }
> ```

Comment: So much for promises :)

Comment: I hope you do read up on the `std::function<>` - it will even allow you to mix methods called on different objects (just use `std::function<void()>` and bind everything or use capturing lambdas). I've included the relevant code from the linked live demo now.

Comment: i waited and then moved on ! i will accept urs, it looks better

Answer (score 2):

#### Introduction

You have currently declared `funcType` as an alias for `void(*)()`, which is a pointer to some function that takes no argument and returns void. What you should be using is a *pointer-to-member-function*, since this will fit the entities which you are trying to invoke.

```
class Sample;
typedef void (Sample::*funcType)();
```

You will also have to *qualify* your member-functions when you are to take their address:

```
void Sample::formList() {
    func_list.push_back(&Sample::method1);
    func_list.push_back(&Sample::method2);
    func_list.push_back(&Sample::method3);
}
```

When invoking a member-function you will need an object on which you would like to call it, this means that you—in order to invoke a member-function throug ha *pointer-to-member-function*—must supply an object at the call site.

```
for (it = sample.func_list.begin(); it != sample.func_list.end(); ++it) {
     (sample.*(*it)) (); // invoke the member-function referred to by `it`
}                        // on the object named `sample`
```

---

**Further Reading**

- [**stackoverflow.com - Calling member-function pointer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/calling-member-function-pointer-c)
- [**cppreference.com - Pointers to member functions**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions)

---

---

#### Sample Implementation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Sample;
typedef void (Sample::*funcType)();

class Sample {
  public:
    vector<funcType> func_list;

    void formList();
    void method1();
    void method2();
    void method3();    
};

void Sample::formList() {
  func_list.push_back(&Sample::method1);
  func_list.push_back(&Sample::method2);
  func_list.push_back(&Sample::method3);
}

void Sample::method1 () {
  cout << "method1" << endl;
}

void Sample::method2 () {
  cout << "method2" << endl;
}

void Sample::method3 () {
  cout << "method3" << endl;
}

int main()
{
  Sample sample; //* = new Sample();
  sample.formList();
  vector<funcType>::iterator it;
  for (it = sample.func_list.begin(); it != sample.func_list.end(); ++it) {
    (sample.*(*it)) ();
  }
}
```

```
method1
method2
method3
```