# calling a C++ member function using the object address and the method address and signature

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

How can I call a method of an object knowing the address of the object and the address of the method(and its signature):

```
auto x = (int(*)())(&A::get_state)
```

Let the object be `x` of type `void*`.

So, using `x` and `m`, `x` of type `void*` and `m` of type `int(*)()`

Comment: Show your complete attempt and which line gives you an error.  Hint: first you must cast the object pointer to the right type, if it is `void*` (I have no idea which is which now because your variables are all nondescriptive single letters).

Comment: `&A::get_state` is probably not `int(*)()` but `int (A::*)() const`.

Comment: There is no attempt because I don't know how should I do this. I can't pass the object parameter to the method, I can't do x->m because x is of type void*

Comment: You are right Jarod. The point is that I try to load the class without knowing the type A

Comment: Object is definitely not of type void* because void* did not have any member functions. :-)

Comment: @Klaus x is of type void* because I loaded the constructor symbol using dlopen and dlsym and then I called the constructor which returned a void*

Comment: Do you try to use some "generic C" function with type erasure `void foo(void (*)(void*), void* userData)` ?

Comment: That cast is putrid. `&A::get_state` already has a type (likely address-of-member function), and you use the proper [member access operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) to invoke it, given a proper, *valid* object pointer.

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, this is what I'm trying to do

Comment: @WhozCraig, it is this way because I do a test, that is why I do the conversion

Comment: If you know that you call a constructor via dlopen the type is of the constructed type and not void. So do a cast... look at http://tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html#loadingclasses

Comment: *"that is why I do the conversion"* - That isn't a conversion; it's a blatant *cast* to an improper type if `get_state` is a regular non-static member function (which we inconveniently cannot tell based solely on your post).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call through a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer)

Comment: So you should show usage of the code and what you want to do. Not asking for a (unclear) sub-problem which is probably not the correct way.

Comment: @nh_ It's not a duplicate because in that example the type is known

Comment: @jarod42 I'll try to understand better the problem in order to put the right question

Comment: You cannot call a member function on an object who's type you don't know. You have to cast your `void*` to that type first and then perform the call. If your actual type may vary, use an interface and cast to that.

Comment: The question did not contain the underlaying problem: dlopen/generic void* C-stype pointers, and all the stuff around. Please provide a full example. The question in the current form is very bad!

Comment: What's an "address" in C++?  C++ has *pointers*, which are somewhat like addresses, but have associated *type* that indicates what they point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question is quite unclear, I just blindly guess what you are trying to do and give a short explanation of how to do that.

---

Typically, plugin mechanisms using shared/dynamic libraries are implemented such that you have an interface.

```
class IPlugin
{
    virtual int doSomething() = 0;
};
```

Next, you implement this interface in your library and, in addition, provide a C function to create an instance of the implementation class (C function, because they are not name-mangled).

```
class MyPlugin : public IPlugin
{
    int doSomething() override { /* ... */ }
};

extern "C" 
{ 
    IPlugin* createPlugin() 
    { 
        return new MyPlugin{}; 
    }
}
```

Now, in your app you load the library using `dlopen` (or `LoadLibrary` on Windows) and fetch the address of your `createPlugin` function using `dlsym` (or `GetProcAddress`):

```
void* addr = dlsym(handle, "createPlugin");
```

Then, you cast this to the actual type, which is equivalent in all libraries:

```
auto createPlugin = reinterpret_cast<IPlugin*(*)()>(addr);
```

By calling `createPlugin` you can now create an instance of your concrete implementation and access it through the interface. There is no need for fetching any additional methods, since `virtual` member functions can be called directly across library boundaries (because of the vtable).

```
IPlugin* plugin = createPlugin();
int result = plugin->doSomething();
```

Same works for functions with arguments and different return types as well, of course. You should however export another C function to destroy the object instance again. `delete` should always be called by the library that created the object (since the library might have been built with a different implementation of `new` than the executable).