# Can this member function selection code be written without std::invoke?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, pointer-to-member, std-invoke

I was trying to select a member `fn` based on some `constexpr` value. I then tried to call the selected function, but I was getting errors about how I am calling member `fn` with incorrect syntax.

```
error: must use '.*' or '->*' to call pointer-to-member function in
'S::SelectedGetter<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>::fn (...)', e.g. '(... ->*
S::SelectedGetter<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>::fn) (...)'     
    18 |     return SelectedGetter<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>::fn();
```

I tried to call it "properly" but failed. In the end I am using `std::invoke`, but I wonder if this can be done without `std::invoke`, using just "raw" C++ syntax.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <type_traits>

static constexpr int number = 18;

struct S
{
    using GetterFn = uint32_t(S::*)() const;
    uint32_t fn1()const {
        return 47;
    }
    uint32_t fn2() const {
        return 8472;
    }

    template <GetterFn Getter1, GetterFn Getter2>
    struct SelectedGetter
    {
        static constexpr GetterFn fn = (number < 11) ? Getter1 : Getter2;
    };

    uint32_t f() {
        return std::invoke((SelectedGetter<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>::fn), this);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    return S{}.f() % 100;
}
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/jno3js)

Note: I am fine with C++20 solutions, for example if some `concept`s magic can help...

Comment: The whole point of `std::invoke` is to simplify usage of function pointers, so use that in place of the weird (imo) `->*` syntax. It is also `constexpr` from c++20 if you need that.

Comment: @JakubDąbek but I presume there is a lot of people who find it harder to read than code in the A

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can call it like [normal member function pointer call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer).
The correct syntax would be

```
 return ((*this).*SelectedGetter<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>::fn)();
```

or

```
return (this->*SelectedGetter<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>::fn)();
```

**([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/W4836c))**

---

Side notes:

- If the functions you call in `f` are `const`, also you could make it also `uint32_t f() const`
- Secondly, you can replace the `SelectedGetter` with a [variable template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variable_template) (since [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14)), and now you need less-typing

It will look like

```
// variable template
template<GetterFn Getter1, GetterFn Getter2>
static constexpr auto fn = (number < 11) ? Getter1 : Getter2;

uint32_t f() const {
   return (this->*fn<&S::fn1, &S::fn2>)();
}
```

**([See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/rYP9sb))**