# How to pass non-static member function as template argument to another member function?

Tags: c++, class, templates, c++17, pointer-to-member

I want to do something like this:

```
struct S
{
   void mf() {};

   template <auto f>
   void func()
   {
      f();
   }
};

int main()
{
   S x;
   x.func<x.mf>();
}
```

However, these are the errors:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'S::func<x.S::mf>()'`
note: candidate: 'template<auto f> void S::func()'
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
error: could not convert 'x.S::mf' from '<unresolved overloaded function type>' to 'void (S::*)()'
```

I am not sure I understand what I am doing wrong.

Why is `x.mf` not resolved since I already instantiated `x`? And how do I make this work?

Comment: One problem is that you need to pass a *pointer* to the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling member functions through a pointer can be so tricky.

You want to pass a member function pointer to `S::mf` [like so](https://wandbox.org/permlink/auF9HFTYAKxW5gW8):

```
struct S
{
    void mf () {std::cout << "called mf\n";};

    template <auto f>
    void func ()
    {
        (this->*f)(); 
    }
};

int main()
{
    S x;
    x.func<&S::mf>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me some keywords to look up on the particular usage of `(this->*f)` and the need for `&S::mf`? Also I tried to use std::function in place of auto but couldn't make it work. I changed it to this version but still couldn't use std::function. What is f deduced exactly in this case?

Comment: @RexYuan the keywords you are looking for are "member function pointer"

Answer (score 1):

`x.mf` is not a type but a member-function pointer.
We must pass it as a parameter.

Here is your modified example (not certain about what you want to do).

```
#include <iostream>

struct S
{
    int i=123;

    void mf () { std::cout << "i=" << i << '\n'; };

    template <typename f>
    void func (f fnct)
    {
        (this->*fnct)();   
    }
};

int main()
{
    S x{456};
    
    x.func(&S::mf);
}
```

Comment: With `auto` templates, we can pass a reference to the function without issue. Without auto, we can still do it, but we have to know the type ahead of time.

Comment: @AndyG Ah ah, thank you for the information. I didn't even know that `template <auto>` existed! (I'm serious)

Comment: Don't be too hard on yourself, it's fairly new syntax

Answer (score 1):

> Why is `x.mf` not resolved since I already instantiated `x`?

Because it is not a valid syntax. There you need to mention the member function by operator `&`, meaning you should have

```
x.func<&S::mf>();
//    ^^^^^^^^
```

So that the template parameter will be deduced to a corresponding member function pointer. That is `void(S::*)()`.

---

> How do I make this work?

The second problem is, the function call `f()` should have been a [call through a member function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer). This is different than the normal function call.

The traditional way of calling the member function pointer with the instance is

```
(this->*f)();
```

However, since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) this is more convenient way using more generic liberary function, so called[`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) from [`<functional>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/functional) header.

Meaning you could do more readable call through a member function pointer like.

```
#include <functional> // std::invoke

template <auto f>
void func()
{
   std::invoke(f, this);
}
```

[See a demo](https://godbolt.org/z/T6333M)