# Pointer to methods problems

Tags: c++, class, syntax, pointer-to-member, member-functions

Well, as I stated in the question: [pointers to members methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68626140/how-to-switch-with-pointer-to-member-functions)

My question: msvc++ is throwing me errors.

If we have:

```
class A 
{
    bool one, two;
    typedef void (A::* RunPtr)(int);
public:
    RunPtr Run;

    A() : one(false), two(false)
    {
        Run = &A::RunOff;
    }
    void SetOne(bool value)
    {
        one = value;
    }
    void SetTwo(bool value)
    {
        two = value;
    }
    void SetOnOrOff()
    {
        if (one || two)
            Run = &A::RunOn;
        else
            Run = &A::RunOff;
    }

    void RunOn(int param)
    {
        //RunOn stuff here
        cout << "RunOn: " << param << endl;
    }

    void RunOff(int param)
    {
        //RunOff stuff here
        cout << "RunOff: " << param << endl;
    }
};
```

Now I want to call, the public `Run` ptr from outside the class.
Say:

```
A a = new A();
a->*Run(10);    // notice that 10 is an int
```

I have tried two ways:

```
a->Run(10)      // Option 1
a->*Run(10)     // Option 2
```

**Option 1** throws me

```
term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

**Option 2** throws me

```
function does not take 1 argument
```

These two errors doesn't let me call the method pointer.

Comment: One question per Stackoverflow question, please. And what exactly is this mysterious type called `Run`? The class defines a private type called `RunPtr`, but, of course, that's not the same.

Comment: Sorry for the two question. I fixed the code anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax to call the member `Run` (which holds the pointer to the member function) with argument is

```
A* a = new A();
(a->*(a->Run))(10);
               ^^^ ---------> argument(s)
     ^^^^^^^^^ -------------> class member "Run"
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^--------------> call to member function pointer syntax

// delete a after use
```

Note that the `a` is a pointer to the class `A`. You need to first dereference the pointer to access its member (i.e. `a->Run`). Now you need the [call to pointer to member function pointer syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer) with dereferencing the pointer `a` once again.

However, call would be much easier using [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke)  (Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17)).

```
#include <functional>   // std::invoke

std::invoke(a->Run, a, 10);
```

**([See a Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ne5zh8q4f))**