# Storing virual functions in Array/Vector container

Tags: c++, class, c++11, callback, pointer-to-member

I have a base class with common behavior and derived classes with override virtual functions. But if tried to save the function pointer as `std::vector` I will get the error:

```
 ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or
  parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.
```

I need something like this:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    virtual int fun1(int inp) = 0;
    virtual int fun2(int inp) = 0;
    int init(int inp, std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> Callbacks, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            return Callbacks[0](inp);
        else
            return Callbacks[1](inp);
    }
    int run()
    {
        return init(5, { &fun1, &fun2 }, 0);
    }
};

class A : public Base
{
    int fun1(int inp)
    {
        return inp * 10;
    }
    int fun1(int inp)
    {
        return inp * 100;
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
    int fun1(int inp)
    {
        return inp * 20;
    }
    int fun2(int inp)
    {
        return inp * 200;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char const* argv[])
{
    auto f = new B;
    int e = f->run();
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to do what I want? Maybe I can bind a virtual function to a container somehow? Or maybe can I set the lambda function as virtual? When I tried to declare lambda function in the `Base` class when I change function in derived class I get errors:

Comment: *ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.* -- I think you need to figure out this error first and understand what it's telling you.  Pointers to member functions are not the same as pointers to non-member, or static, or "free" functions.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I understand why I get this error. fun1  & fun2 are non-static functions. But I can't declare these ones as static 'cos virtual functions can not be static.

Comment: How do you declare a pointer to a non-static member function, and then call it via pointer?  That's the point I'm making -- accomplish that first, and things will get clearer.

Comment: A virtual function is just a placeholder. You need to define it in a derived class for the compiler to get its address. Thats why a virtual function cannot be stored in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a "pointer" to a member with the syntax `&Class::Member` (`Class::Member` is the "qualified" name of the member).

These are pointers only in an abstract sense, and need to be dereferenced relative to an object.
You do this with the `->*` or `.*` operator, depending on whether the left-hand side is a pointer or not.
Note that you must use `this` explicitly, if that is the relevant object.

The type of `&Base::fun1` and `&Base::fun2` is `int (Base::*)(int)`, which can't be converted to `std::function<int(int)>`.

Putting it together:

```
int init(int inp, std::vector<int (Base::*)(int)> Callbacks, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return (this->*Callbacks[0])(inp); // The leftmost parentheses are necessary.
    else
        return (this->*Callbacks[1])(inp);
}

int run()
{
    return init(5, {&Base::fun1, &Base::fun2}, 0);
}
```

If you don't want to limit the callbacks to members, you can use lambda functions, capturing `this`:

```
int init(int inp, std::vector<std::function<int(int))> Callbacks, int index)
{
    if (index == 0)
        return Callbacks[0](inp);
    else
        return Callbacks[1](inp);
}

int run()
{
    return init(5, 
                {[this](int i) { return fun1(i); },
                 [](int) { return 567; } }, 
                0);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code has several issues:

1. Pointers to member functions are not the same as pointers to non-member, or static, or "free" functions. That means the type here `std::function<int(int)>` is wrong as it meant for free functions or static functions.
2. The call to the member function pointer is not the same as the normal function call. You need to [specify the object to which you are calling the member function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer). Since C++17 you can also invoke the pointer to member function using more generic [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke).
3. You only need to init the `Callbacks` once (probably in the contractor), and use it in `run` later.
4. Upon passing the member function pointer, you need the syntax `&ClassName::MemberFunction`, which you have missed in the function call `init(5, {&fun1, &fun2}, 0);`.
5. The `Base` required a [virtual destructor for defined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors), in case you store the children in the `Base` class pointer at a later point.

Following is the example code as per the above changes:

```
#include <functional> // std::invoke

class Base
{
    // member function pointer type
    using MemFunPtrType = int(Base::*)(int);
    // to store the member functions pointers
    std::vector<MemFunPtrType> mMemberFunctionPts; 

public:
    Base() // initlize the mMemberFunctionPts once!
        : mMemberFunctionPts{ { &Base::fun1, &Base::fun2 } }
    {}
    virtual int fun1(int inp) = 0;
    virtual int fun2(int inp) = 0;
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    // run choose the correct member function as per the passed index!
    int run(std::size_t index)
    {
        if (2u == mMemberFunctionPts.size() && index == 0)
            return (this->*mMemberFunctionPts[index])(5);
            // or using std::invoke
            // return std::invoke(mMemberFunctionPts[index], this, 5);
        else
            return (this->*mMemberFunctionPts[index])(5);
    }
};
```

See a **([Live Demo Here](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/jh1z7vGqK))**

Comment: std function uses the INVOKE concept; you could have kept std function around.

Answer (score 0):

@PaulMcKenzie, thanks. Now it works:

```cpp
class Base
{
public:
    std::function<int(int)> fun1;
    std::function<int(int)> fun2;
    int init(int inp, std::vector<std::function<int(int)>> Callbacks, int index)
    {
        if (index == 0)
            return Callbacks[0](inp);
        else
            return Callbacks[1](inp);
    }

    int run()
    {
        return init(5, {&fun1, &fun2}, 0);
    }
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    B()
    {
        fun1 = fun1B;
        fun2 = fun2B;
    }

private:
    std::function<int(int)> fun1B = [&](int inp)
    {
        return inp * 20;
    };
    std::function<int(int)> fun2B = [&](int inp)
    {
        return inp * 200;
    };
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    auto f = new B();
    int e = f->run();
    assert(e == 5*20);
    return 0;
}
```

But the example above looks more correct.