# Function pointer to class method as argument

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, pointer-to-member, function-call

As you can see by my code, I'm trying to create a `onClick` event for a button that invoke a function from another class (I'm trying to make my custom button class instead of using `win32` default ones for testing).

But even if this does not throw any error, it just doesn't invoke the given method.

This is the function signature inside **Button.hpp**

```
void onClick(POINT pt, void (ButtonsHandler::*clicked)(void));
```

This is the implementation inside `Button.cpp` (Using `clicked()` throws C++ expression preceding parentheses of apparent call must have pointer-to function type)

```
void Button::onClick(POINT pt, void (ButtonsHandler::*clicked)(void)) 
{
    if (PtInRect(&textRect, pt) != 0) 
    {
        clicked;
    }
}
```

And this is where I actually call it

```
mainMenu.getPlay().onClick(pt, &ButtonsHandler::onPlay);
```

EDIT: solved thank you guys
I was just not creating a ButtonsHandler object to execute the non-static function
Here's the correct code I was missing.

```
void Button::onClick(POINT pt, void (ButtonsHandler::*clicked)(void)) {
    if (PtInRect(&textRect, pt) != 0) {
        ButtonsHandler bh;
        (bh.*clicked)();
    }
}
```

Comment: `clicked;` is a valid expression but it doesn't call anything (assuming you intended this). How about `clicked();`?

Comment: how about *this* pointer ? if you call class method you must pass pointer to class. where you try do this ?

Comment: @JeJo Yes. And the missing instance pointer to the `ButtonsHandler` (or its unknown relation to `Button`) is yet another issue which is unclear from the exposed info. But, anyway: No brackets - no call. ;-) (and I was assuming that adding the brackets might cause a new error which leads into the right direction)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> It just doesn't invoke the given method!

The passed [pointer to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer) has to be called to get in effect.

I assume that the `Button` is inherited from the `ButtonsHandler`. Then, for instance, you can call with the pointer to member function with `this` pointer as follows:

```
void Button::onClick(POINT pt, void (ButtonsHandler::*clicked)(void)) 
{
    if (PtInRect(&textRect, pt) != 0) {
        (this->*clicked)();
        //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        // or
        // std::invoke(clicked, this) // need to include <functional> header(Since C++17)
    }
}
```

---

If both classes are unrelated, you required an instance of `ButtonsHandler` to call the member function. For example:

```
ButtonsHandler obj;
(obj.*clicked)();
// or
// std::invoke(clicked, obj) // need to include <functional> header
```