# Error in vector of struct with implemented Functions

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, std-function, pointer-to-member

I get the Erro:

```
"no instance of constructor "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::vector 
 [with _Ty=FunctionToUpdate, _Alloc=std::allocator<FunctionToUpdate>]" matches the argument list"
```

No matter how I change it, it persists, as long I keep it as a class. If I keep it all in just a simple `.cpp` without class and header, it all resolves easily.
My.h:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Params
{
    std::vector<int> Integers;
    std::vector<std::string> Strings;
};

struct FunctionToUpdate
{
    int Version;
    std::function<void(int, Params)> Function;
    Params Parameters;
};

class Error
{
public:
    Error();
    void testFunctionA(int a, Params p);
    void testFunctionB(int a, Params p);
protected:
    const static std::vector<FunctionToUpdate> table;
};
```

Here is my `.cpp`, please assist me, I can't find the error:

```
#include "ErrorHandling.h"

Error::Error()
{
    for (auto functionToUpdate : table)
    {
        functionToUpdate.Function(functionToUpdate.Version, functionToUpdate.Parameters);
        std::cout << "############################################" << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Done!" << std::endl;
}

void Error::testFunctionA(int a, Params parameter)
{
    //std::cout << "Size Integers: " << parameter.Integers.size() << std::endl;
    //std::cout << "Size Strings: " << parameter.Strings.size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << a << std::endl;

    for (auto& integer : parameter.Integers)
    {
        std::cout << integer << std::endl;
    }
    for (auto& integer : parameter.Strings)
    {
        std::cout << integer << std::endl;
    }
}

void Error::testFunctionB(int a, Params parameter)
{
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << parameter.Integers.at(0) << std::endl;
}

const std::vector<FunctionToUpdate> Error::table
{                                                       // <-- here the Error happens
    { 100, &testFunctionA, { {177}}},
    { 1948, &testFunctionB, { {314}}},
};

int main()
{
    Error error;
}
```

Comment: The syntax for acquiring a pointer-to-member is `&ClassName::MemberName`. And you can't convert a pointer-to-member-function to a `std::function`.

Comment: @molbdnilo yes pointer to member function can be converted to `std::function`, though not like OP is doing it. A `R (X::*)(T...)` can be assigned to a `std::function<R(X*,T...)>` for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few issues

1. First, the correct initialization of static member `Error::table` would be as follows:

   ```
   const std::vector<FunctionToUpdate> Error::table
   {                                                  
       { 100, &Error::testFunctionA, { { {177} }, { {"string"} } }},
       { 1948, &Error::testFunctionB, { { {314} }, { {"string"} } } }
   };
   ```

   Note that the syntax `&Error::testFunctionA` for addressing the member function pointer. Additionally, the `Params` has two vectors. One is `std::vector<int>` and the other is `std::vector<std::string>`. In your code, the `std::vector<std::string>` has not been mentioned.

2. In `FunctionToUpdate` the member function pointer type is wrong. Using [typed member function pointer](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members), you could

   ```
   // forward declaration
   class Error;
   // member function pointer type
   using ErrorFunType = void(Error::*)(int, Params);

   struct FunctionToUpdate
   {
       int Version;
       ErrorFunType Function;
       Params Parameters;
   };
   ```
3. Secondly, the call to pointer to the member function in `Error::Error()` is wrong. [It needs an (`Error` class) instance to call with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer). For example:

   ```
   for (auto functionToUpdate : table)
   {
      (this->*functionToUpdate.Function)(
         functionToUpdate.Version, functionToUpdate.Parameters
      );
      // or more generic `std::invoke` (since c++17)
      // std::invoke(functionToUpdate.Function
      //    , this, functionToUpdate.Version
      //    , functionToUpdate.Parameters);
      // ...
   }
   ```

The above changes will make, your code [compiles again](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3G3YEe334)!

---

In case of wondering, how to handle the pointer to member function with `std::function`, (one way) to wrap the instance to call the member along with the `std::function` type.

Following is the example:

```
// forward declaration
class Error;
// member function pointer
using ErrorFunType = std::function<void(Error*, int, Params)>;

struct FunctionToUpdate
{
    int Version;
    ErrorFunType Function;
    Params Parameters;
};
```

now in `Error::Error()`

```
Error::Error()
{
    for (auto functionToUpdate : table)
    {
        functionToUpdate.Function(this
            , functionToUpdate.Version, functionToUpdate.Parameters);
    }
}
```

**[See a demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/Mz6EnYYa7)**

Comment: Works perfectly fine and explanation helps a bunch understanding more about <functions>. Thanks a lot! :)