# Pass member function as argument to another function?

Tags: c++, function, robotics

I'm trying to code a robot for fun.  I want to add an Autonomous loop so the robot can follow a set of preset commands and drive itself.  The issue is, each subsystem of the robot is a different class, and I want to be able to create a function somewhat like this:

```cpp
DoFunctionForMe(start_time, end_time, function, start_arguments, end_arguments);
```

What I want the `DoFunctionForMe` to do is execute the function with the start arguments at the start time, and execute the end arguments at the end time.

So for example I could have the following that will drive from time 1 to time 8, AND move from time 7 to time 9:

```cpp
void Robot::AutoMainLoop(){
    DoFunctionForMe(1,8,Drive,{12,12},{0,0});
    DoFunctionForMe(7,9,Move,{1,0},{0,0});
}
```

Heres an approximation of the code I have so far:

```cpp
class Drivetrain{
    public:
        Drivetrain();

        void Drive(int forward, int left){
            drive(forward, left); // Drives the robot, more complex than this 
        }
}

class Mechanism{
    public:
        Mechanism();

        void Move(int up, int down){
            move(up, down); // Moves the arm, more complex than this
        }
}

class Robot{
    public:
        void DrivenMainLoop(); // Operated by a person

        void AutoMainLoop(); // Robot operates itself

    private:
        Drivetrain m_drivetrain{}; 

        Mechanism m_mechanism{};

}

void Robot::DrivenMainLoop(){
    m_drivetrain.Drive(2,12);

    m_mechanism.Move(1,0);

}

void Robot::AutoMainLoop(){
    // help
}
```

Is there a way I can do this?

I've tried using pointers to the functions, but I don't really understand what I'm doing there, and It gives me errors such as `a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call through a member function pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12189057/how-to-call-through-a-member-function-pointer)

Comment: That still doesn't explain how to pass the function to another function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Drive` and `Move` methods are non-static members of separate classes. You will have to use `std::bind()`+`std::function`, or a lambda, in order for `DoFunctionForMe()` to call them without knowing which objects they come from, eg:

```
class Drivetrain {
    public:
        ...

        void Drive(int forward, int left) {
            ...
        }
};

class Mechanism {
    public:
        ...

        void Move(int up, int down) {
            ...
        }
};

class Robot {
    public:
        ...

        void AutoMainLoop(); // Robot operates itself

    private:
        Drivetrain m_drivetrain{}; 

        Mechanism m_mechanism{};
};

...

void DoFunctionForMe(..., std::function<void(int,int)> the_function, ...) {
    ...
    the_function(arg1, arg2);
    ...
}

/* or:

template<typename Callable>
void DoFunctionForMe(..., Callable the_function, ...) {
    ...
    the_function(arg1, arg2);
    ...
}
*/

void Robot::AutoMainLoop() {
    using namespace std::placeholders;

    auto drive = std::bind(&Drivetrain::Drive, &m_drivetrain, _1, _2);
    DoFunctionForMe(..., drive, ...);

    auto move = std::bind(&Mechanism::Move, &m_mechanism, _1, _2);
    DoFunctionForMe(..., move, ...);

    // or:

    DoFunctionForMe(..., [&](int arg1, int arg2){ m_drivetrain.Drive(arg1, arg2); }, ...);
    DoFunctionForMe(..., [&](int arg1, int arg2){ m_mechanism.Move(arg1, arg2); }, ...);
}
```

Alternatively, you can make `Drivetrain` and `Mechanism` inherit from a common base class that defines a `virtual` method which they both override, and then you can make `DoFunctionForMe()` operate on that base class via polymorphism, eg:

```
class Actionable {
    public:
        virtual void DoAction(int arg1, int arg2) = 0;
};

class Drivetrain : public Actionable {
    public:
        ...

        void Drive(int forward, int left) {
            ...
        }

        void DoAction(int arg1, int arg2) override {
            Drive(arg1, arg2);
        }
};

class Mechanism : public Actionable {
    public:
        ...

        void Move(int up, int down) {
            ...
        }

        void DoAction(int arg1, int arg1) override {
            Move(arg1, arg2);
        }
};

class Robot {
    public:
        ...

        void AutoMainLoop(); // Robot operates itself

    private:
        Drivetrain m_drivetrain{}; 

        Mechanism m_mechanism{};
};

...

void DoFunctionForMe(..., Actionable &actionable, ...) {
    ...
    actionable.DoAction(arg1, arg2);
    ...
}

void Robot::AutoMainLoop() {
    DoFunctionForMe(..., m_drivetrain, ...);
    DoFunctionForMe(..., m_mechanism, ...);
}
```